# Dual-Boot Windows XP Config using VMWare

Tags: windows-xp, vmware

Ugh!
I had just spent a good 3 hours and can't figure it out!!!

My PC rig is a bit old, and I don't have a physical CD-Rom to be able to install WinXP the usual way.

I do however, have an extra NTSC partition, cleanly formatted for Windows installation. Both partitions are part of the same physical hard-drive.

What I'm trying to do is install a clean operating system, move all of my important files, then install something else onto the original OS. I am trying to configure Multi-OS environment for apps developer purposes. So I will have Windows 7, Windows Vista, and WinXP.

I am using the VMWare player but my main concern is, will I be able to boot up outside of virtual environment?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is geared more towards superuser.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate Partition on your physical drive you can install Directly to improve the performance.
You can boot it from a XP image file either on your hard disk or from USB (Preferably).